# How to atomically print lines from multiple background processes in a bash script?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

In a bash function I'm writing I start multiple remote commands via ssh, and have them run in separate background processes. Each of these processes produces many lines of text, which are merged together and then sorted. My problem is that sometimes these lines are mixed together. That is one line starts printing and before that line is finished printing, another line starts printing on the same line.

My question is what is the simplest way to make this print output atomic so that the individual lines don't blend together (interspersing whole lines is ok -- I just want the columns to line up)? One idea I had was to save the output for each parallel background process and then merge them serially, but I have not been able to get this to work (this method should work fine for me if I knew how to properly do it). For reference, here is an outline of the type of script I'm trying to write:

```
foo() {
    (
        pids=()
        for x in "$@"
        do
            (
                ssh $x 'some-high-latency-command-with-200-lines-of-data-output'
            ) &
            pids+=( $! )
        done
        for x in "${pids[@]}"
        do
            wait $x
        done
    ) 2> /dev/null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would redirect each `ssh` run to its own file and merge them afterward.  I also wouldn't use a `wait` loop; `wait` by itself will wait for all backgrounded processes, or you can say `wait ${pids[*]}` if you really want just the `ssh` processes.

Comment: Thanks, that syntax for wait simplifies things a bit but essentially does the same thing as the for loop in more compact notation. It would be nice to do this without creating files though.

Comment: The shell can't really do that kind of thing itself, though.  You could try having the backgrounded `ssh` be a backgrounded `ssh ... | while read l; do echo "$l" >>file; done`, which will be rather slow because of the gratuitous loop whose sole purpose is to perform line buffering instead of unbuffered or block-buffered output. Depending on what you're doing with the data afterward, pushing off the merge step until afterward will work better and be more reliable than tricky `ssh`-to-shell-script pipelines.

Comment: I'm actually just piping the output into `less` and selecting subsets of the lines with `&` to compare various stats across the machines. I don't even need to keep the data persistently. These are relatively short experiments, taking just about 10 seconds on up to 8-10 machines in parallel. However, I'm running these tests frequently, hence the benefit of the script instead of comparing the individual outputs by hand.

Answer (score 3):

I finally stumbled onto a solution that appears to work without creating files. Apparently, if I assign the output of ssh to a variable with `declare`, the lines are preserved, and using `echo` to print from this variable appears to be atomic. See the following:

```
foo() {
    (
        pids=()
        for x in "$@"
        do
            (
                declare output=$(ssh $x 'some-command-with-multiline-output')
                echo "$output"
            ) &
            pids+=( $! )
        done
        wait ${pids[*]}
    ) 2> /dev/null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use some program to recompose lines locally before printing them, for instance:

```
ssh $x 'some-high-latency-command-with-200-lines-of-data-output' | perl -pe1
```